# In NetLogo can I ask agents to die along a gradient from a central patch?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have agents sprout at random throughout the environment. I'd like to  to have a density gradient of these agents.

Is there a neater way to do it than running something like this for different radii?:

```
ask patch 0 0 [ask n-of 20 turtles in-radius 20 [die]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something along those lines:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  let max-distance max [ distancexy 0 0 ] of patches
  ask patches [
    if random-float 1.0 > (distancexy 0 0 / max-distance) [
      sprout 1
    ]
  ]
end
```

Many variants are possible. The key is to use a combination of `random-float` and `distancexy 0 0` to get the density you want.