# netlogo patch affected by distance from a certain patch

Tags: distance, netlogo

I would like to ask how i can set up patches.

Initial condition is there is a red patch at a certain point. The other patches will be affected by a distance from the red patch. As a distance go far, the impact will be greater.

It might not be simple as a beginner. please help me out!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856220/in-netlogo-can-i-ask-agents-to-die-along-a-gradient-from-a-central-patch for a very similar question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edited to include Nicholas' commends

```
 to example

  let red-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = red]

  ask red-patch [
    ask other patches [
      if random-float 1 > (distance red-patch / (max [distance red-patch] of patches))
        [set pcolor blue]
    ]
  ]
end
```

This would have it be a gradient effect so they are more likely to be blue the closer they are to the red patch. Flipping the > to a < just inverses the effect.

Comment: There is a subtle mistake in this code: only the first occurrence of `myself` refers to the red patch. The second `myself`, being inside an `of` block, refers to the current patch from the `ask other patches` block. It _seems_ to work nonetheless because, when world wrapping is turned on, the max distance between any two patches is the same. If world wrapping is turned off, however, `max [distance myself] of patches` will vary from patch to patch. I would suggest starting with `let red-patch one-of patches with [ pcolor = red ]` and referring to the red patch explicitly. `myself` is tricky!

Comment: Nah, not so silly; it's very easy to miss that an `of` block changes the context that `myself` is relative to.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Nicolas!